# How do I have standalone java console app to open up the browser with login page and read the page content

Tags: java

We are going to distribute a standalone java console application to our customers. We want application to open up a web browser with login page (login with amazon), let the user login, and read the 4 digit code that is displayed in on the web browser page after log in is done. How can I do that using java application including application should be able to read the code.

I looked into Selenium but i think that is more for a test framework and not the real product.

Any suggestion?

to be more specific, i want to do something like this, but after that, read the text that is displayed in the browser.

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.awt.Desktop; 

java.awt.Desktop desktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();
String arg="Your URI here";
java.net.URI uri = new java.net.URI( arg );
desktop.browse( uri );
```

Comment: Are you asking about screen scraping?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a javascript webapp?

Comment: actually you need a framework like Selenium

Comment: I don't really understand the use case. Can you elaborate? It sounds a little bit weird.

Comment: @killjoy , Not sure about the question. the web page i am opening is login with amazon page.

Comment: @Michael --> we are trying to implement oauth flow here using login with amazon. User run the java app on his computer and talk with backend. but all the backend call needs to be authorized. We are using login with amazon for auth stuff. meaning, we want the java app to open up the page where user can log in. after that login with amaozn system redirects the user to a page with auth code in uri... we want java app to read that code and after that talk to our back-end system

Comment: @m.antkowicz, can't use selenium... it is more suitable for testing. right?

Comment: Selenium is a perfectly valid solution for your usecase. It really is just a containerized chromium that loads your webpage in its own window. If you're really doing java, it's simple enough to open the amazon login page in the browser using the `Runtime` class. If you want to handle some extra logic after the login completes, you may want to use javascript instead of java (JavaScript runs in the browser, Java does not), because it runs directly inside the container. Anything else and you may want to use a server solution.

Comment: I recommend that you include a simple webserver in your application so that it can be used for the OAuth callback (on localhost).

Comment: Responding to your update with code: After you launch the browser, you cannot interact with it because it is a separate process. You will need to use javascript to call back to a local socket.

Comment: @Michael, Already thought about that and it was on the table. but did not pass security bar. Local host is the easiest way but can;t use it.

Comment: It is the only sane choice in my opinion. (Mis)using Selenium or something else for extracting tokens is a really bad idea.

Comment: @killjoy . thank you. Is there any example code you can point me to about how would i do that?

Comment: Otherwise consider a proper web app / frontend.

Comment: @Michael, too late for web based front end. Java pp is the only way we have right now.